# How does one prevent labels of different Swift cells displaying on top of each other?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, prepareforreuse

[Screenshot of the double text label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reZwD.png)

[Current constraints of the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUOFZ.png)

[Complete Hirearchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpRtL.png)

What is my relevant code currently

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ViewControllerTableViewCell {
        let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
        let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]
        let text = person.Education
        
        cell.lblName.text = person.Education. ///key line
        cell.lblName.text = text?.uppercased()
        cell.lblName?.layer.masksToBounds = true
       
        let person5 = colorArray[indexPath.row]
        let person6 = colorArray1[indexPath.row]
        let person7 = colorArray2[indexPath.row]
        
    
        let like = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UIButton
        
        cell.backgroundColor = person5
        like?.backgroundColor = person6
        immy?.backgroundColor = person7
        
        cell.lblName.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
        cell.postID = self.people[indexPath.row].postID
        
        cell.row = indexPath.row
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.delegate2 = self
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            like?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

**What have I tried**:

In prepare for reuse, I tried `lblName.text = "" and lblName.text = nil` Didn't work.

I also tried in cellForRowAt:

```
 cell.lblName.text = nil
 if cell.lblName.text == nil{
 cell.lblName.text = person.Education
}
```

I also tried to get it done by constraints, no luck.

**What I think might be cause**

This didn't happen before I changed from TableViewController scene to ViewController(with an output table) scene.

It also didn't happen before I set the cells to have different colors.

Comment: It looks like you have two labels that overlap each other. You need to set constraints to prevent that -- but you haven't shown us anything about how you have your cell laid out.

Comment: it's by setting constrains for each view to prevent overlapping

Comment: @DonMaf and Ali A. Jalil I have now added the current constraints and the hierarchy of the VC with the label in the question. What constraint is missing? These constraints worked previously when I was using TableViewController

Comment: @florida27 - very confusing... your image shows a `label2` but your code refers to `.lblName` ... you also show several buttons, but your "screenshot" doesn't show any buttons ... there is absolutely no need to set `.text = nil` before setting `.text = person.Education` ... show us a screenshot that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swg77.png  so we can understand what you are doing.

Comment: @DonMag the referencing outlet of label2 is lblName-cell. Sorry about buttons, only the button with the redacted name is active. The others are just translucent buttons that don't do anything. Here is the scene like your example with that part un-redacted:  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpRtL.png)

Comment: @florida27 - sorry, but that's still very confusing. Your layout image doesn't really show what's what (other than the image view). On `label2` you have `height = 170` and `aspect = 149:170`, which means its `width` will be `149` ... but then you give it a 2nd width constraint: `label2.width = 0.32 x width`. In addition, you don't seem to have any position constraints on `Immy`. I suggest you start fresh... New cell, add only `lblName` label, with position and size constraints. See what happens. Assuming it works, add the other elements one-by-one.

Comment: the second 0.32 width constraint is in proportion to superview. In other words the three cells respective are 0.32 0.32 and 0.36 with makes 1, ie total proportional width of superview. The 149 width is the width of the cell, with superview having 414 width, so 0.36 proportional. As to this problem, I am still testing but it seems to work after checking clear graphics context on label2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by checking clear graphics context on label2.

Answer (score -1):

i think your problem would solve if you check cell heights ,
check heightForCellAtRow Func

Answer (score -1):

I havent seen at your cell class. That issue happens when you have constraints issues. Since the autolayout system is unable to calculate the height of the row, the height becomes 0, any change from that point forward might be wrong.

I would suggest you check the cell code, add the labels to the contentView (if they are not) and add constraints between them:

eg:

```
bottomLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
```

also set the compression resistance for both labels to be .defaultHigh and if you have the height of the row hardcoded remove that.

Comment: But it is one label not 2